# Service registry Pattern for Web API deployed ASE

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, consul, azure-app-service-envrmnt, steeltoe

I have multiple APIs deployed to Azure ASE for internal and external use. Internal API are developed for reuse. I am looking for service registry which maintains all API details at one place for developer or analyst to identify the API for design and dev work. Currently I am looking into Consul and Eureka but they are used for containerised .net application. Can we use for the services deployed to ASE? or is there any other better solution available?
Azure APIM already in place and it is used to exposed API which are consumed by external/internal systems.

Comment: Eureka and Consul are like the phone book for app instances... They don't particularly care where the app instances live, they just keep track of those addresses as instances come and go. They can be used to hold registrations for app instances running anywhere, but aren't serving the same purpose as Azure API Management

Answer (score -1):

Azure api management would be one of the option you can considering  you  want to manage your api and also provide developer options.

Azure api Management consist of three components, an API gateway, a management plane, and a developer portal.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) for Indepth explanation.